# How concat two sql query in a single result

Tags: mysql

I have two sql query

***First:***

```
SELECT ticketing_ticket.id, ticketing_ticket.email,
CONCAT(
TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,date_create,date_close) , ' jours ',
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,date_create,date_close), 24), ' heures ',
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,date_create,date_close), 60), ' miinutes '
) AS 'temps de traitement '
FROM ticketing_ticket WHERE DATE(date_close) = CURDATE();
```

***Output:***

```
   |  email       |       Time
   |test@test.com | 15 jours 23 heures 7 miinutes 
   |test@test.com | 15 jours 22 heures 54 miinutes
```

***Second:***

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(T2.label SEPARATOR ';') AS 'Domaines'
FROM (
    SELECT
        @r AS _id,
        (SELECT @r := id_parent FROM ticketing_category WHERE id_category = _id) AS parent_id,
        @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
    FROM
        (SELECT @r := 38, @l := 0) vars,
        ticketing_category m
    WHERE @r <> 0) T1
JOIN ticketing_category T2
ON T1._id = T2.id_category
ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC
```

***Output:***

```
 |          Domaines           | 
 |Elections;Aides et démarches |
```

How Can i combine my sql query  in a single result like this

```
|  email       |       Time                        | Domaines           
|test@test.com |    15 jours 23 heures 7 miinutes  | Elections;Aides et démarches 
|test@test.com |    15 jours 22 heures 54 miinutes | Elections;Aides et démarches
```

***UPDATE:***

My connection between ticket and ticketing_category is id_category

[image]

Comment: What is that good for, if one column always have the same value for all rows? And why do you have an ORDER BY clause in a single-row-statement? It's not even valid SQL, and should fail with strict mode.

Comment: If you want an answer that's really worth 50 reputation it would help if you provided some sample data and an explanation of how the output is supposed to be achieved.

Comment: Please provide some sample data

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. That includes using language to actually clearly explain what "merge" & "combine" mean, ie what your example is an example of. PS Setting & reading the same variable in a select statement in MySQL is undefined. See the manual. People at Percona have shown by examining the code that *certain idioms* work *in the current implementation*.

Comment: You can create a `view` in MySQL. by Joining two queries. and, when you'll query it will be same as querying a table.

Comment: You will need to provide more information to get a better answer, what are the field names of your tables:  ticketing_ticket,ticketing_category and which two fields do you want to join(and with what criteria if any).

The only this that i can see clearly is that you want your output to have columns
1. email
2. 'temps de traitement'
3. Domaines

Comment: @Mercer It may be well worth it to investigate schema some more. What's the connection between ticket and ticketing_category? There should be one, and it could be used for a join between those two result sets.

Comment: @przemo_li i upadte my post

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to have no requirements on how to connect the records, you can simply do a cross join.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ticketing_ticket.email,
CONCAT(
TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,date_create,date_close) , ' jours ',
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,date_create,date_close), 24), ' heures ',
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,date_create,date_close), 60), ' miinutes '
) AS 'temps de traitement '
FROM ticketing_ticket WHERE DATE(date_close) = CURDATE()
) a,
(
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(T2.label SEPARATOR ';') AS 'Domaines'
FROM (
    SELECT
        @r AS _id,
        (SELECT @r := id_parent FROM ticketing_category WHERE id_category = _id) AS parent_id,
        @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
    FROM
        (SELECT @r := 38, @l := 0) vars,
        ticketing_category m
    WHERE @r <> 0) T1
JOIN ticketing_category T2
ON T1._id = T2.id_category
ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC
) b;
```

Comment: in `SELECT @r := 38..` i want to use the `ticketing_ticket` result from the first request (alias a in your example)

Comment: But your first query doesn't return an integer value. Please clarify further.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
    DECLARE @Tickets TABLE (
    TicketId INT,
    Email VARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @Domaines TABLE (
    DomaineId INT,
    DomainName VARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @TicketDomaine Table(
    TicketId INT,
    DomaineId VARCHAR(15)
)

INSERT INTO @Tickets
    SELECT 1, 'test@gmail.com'
    UNION SELECT 2, 'test2@gmail.com'

INSERT INTO @Domaines
    SELECT 1, 'Élections'
    UNION SELECT 2, 'Aides et démarches'

INSERT INTO @TicketDomaine
    SELECT 1, 1
    UNION SELECT 1, 2
    UNION SELECT 2, 1

SELECT      
 T.TicketId
 , ISNULL((SELECT D.DomainName + ',' AS [data()]    
    FROM @TicketDomaine TD  
    INNER JOIN @Domaines D ON TD.DomaineId = D.DomaineId
    WHERE  TD.TicketId = T.TicketId
    FOR XML PATH('')), '') 'Mots-clés'  
FROM @Tickets T
    --WHERE T.TicketId = 2
```

**Output:**

```
1   Élections, Aides et démarches,
2   Élections,
```